# Django AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have 2 models Profiles and Events. I want to save the number of events created by the user to the users profile, such that even if the events are deleted the record stays in the users profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_events = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='seller')
    ...
```

Below are my views

```
class CreateEvent(IsVerifiedMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = 'event/event_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        print(self.object.user.profile.total_events) #This prints 0
        self.object.user.profile.total_events += 1
        print(self.object.user.profile.total_events) # This prints 1
        self.object.user.profile.total_events.save() # If I don't use this statement it does not save to database. But It gives me the above error
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> This line `self.object.user.profile.total_events.save()` gives me the error

How do I fix this error. I tried adding a variable and saving the variable but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_events` is an integer that's part of your `Profile` model.

you want to execute save on a model instance, not a model field.

`self.objects.user.profile.save()` should work